# WES7 - Custom Shell - How to Install Dependencies

Tags: windows-7, installation, shell, unattended, windows-embedded-7

#### Summary

Using the Image Configuration Editor for Windows Embedded Standard 7, how can I install applications before a custom shell is started?

#### Background

I'm designing an unattended image for **Windows Embedded Standard 7**, and while I can get my applications to install okay when my shell is set to command prompt (CMD.EXE), I cannot run the installation when I use my custom shell, because the specified shell is dependent on all of the applications I need to install.

I'm using FirstLogonCommands with SynchronousCommand to install the required files (in pass 7 OOBE). It seems the shell tries to launch before these run, resulting in shell failure and the commands not to continue. Is there any way I can ensure the SynchronousCommands finish before the shell is launched? I've tried moving the commands to passes: specialize and audit user, but the same thing happens.

#### Notes

An example of an "application" I need to install is .NET framework 4.5, a USB driver and a display driver.

Answer (score 0):

I typically end up doing build and captures to deploy an image to mulitple identical computers.  For installing things and chhanging configuration (including autologin), Windows Embedded Standard 7 supports using SetupComplete.CMD.  Here is a [short description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766314%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft.  A couple of caveats:

1. It is only run if you run sysprep on the machine
2. No user interaction can occur
3. On Windows Embedded Industry 8/8.1, the type of license you have changes whether or not it is run. For Windows Embedded 8, I have not had this issue.

It it does run before the login screen is shown.

In general, I would also suggest installing .NET prior to capturing an image, since you often have to immediately apply patches after installation.